How to define a member function within a member function's scope?
This question is on ease of use. My ultimate want is that when I collapse a class'es code except for the class body scope, that what I see and read is as brief and necessary as possible, implying all attributes and members.
I have a class template with member template function eval_sub that is only used within the member function eval. While arguable to remove eval_sub, it helps eval's ease-of-read that eval_sub exists like so. However, I dislike eval_sub's visiblity upon collapse of eval's definition -- because eval_sub is only relevant for eval.
template<int n>
struct A{
  double x;
  template<int k> void eval_sub(){
    x+=exp(k);
  }
  void eval(){
    [this]<std::size_t... k>(std::index_sequence<k...>){ (eval_sub<k>(), ...); }(std::make_index_sequence<n>{});
  }
};

Question: How do I hide eval_sub within the scope of eval?
What I tried:

auto lambda works obviously but I refuse it for several reasons. 1) auto is inexplicit. 2) Explitisation is unhelpful not because of language illness in pointer lingo but because of the overarching fact that such pointer (a.k.a. the "lambda") is never needed. Case in point is that I do not need to put eval_sub's address into a variable just in order to call it. Rather is the auto lambda a jailbreak to just prevent the compiler from refusing a function definition within a function scope.
putting a struct static in front of eval_sub destroys the member-function characterization, in that before every attribute access within eval_sub I'd now have to grab a handle of A's this, which obliterates utility.

How do you approach this common problem? My present solution is that I live with the annoyance upon scope collapse of reading about 10 class members when really there should be only about three.
PS: I know what the language forbids. I am curious how language consumers (i.e., this audience) trade this dilemma. What is your typical way of proceeding in this case? If the answer is "auto lambda" then I give in.

You can't define functions inside other functions in c++. There are workarounds like using lambda etc but still that doesn't technically mean you can define function inside function.

I don't see any real problem with using lambda here.

@user12002570 But don't you, actually? I mean I could define eval_sub in eval by pretending it was a variable assignment via the auto lambda trick. That's for me a definition within a definition.

Hi. I do use c++ but your code is very confusing to me. Why are you using template<int> - that's no template I'm aware of. As for returning auto, this is becoming preferred practice in C++, no need to run from it. You can define a lambda function within a function, but that's about it. Classes are usually used for encapsulation. I don't fully understand your want, but namespace is also used for encapsulation. You can also put the code in its own compilation unit (source file) and not export it. Maybe add some pseudo-code for what you want to be able to do for clarity.

@user23311233 "That's for me a definition within a definition...." That is a trick/workaround. A lambda is not a function. It is an anonymous struct with certain member function overloaded that allows us to functionally do what functions allow. That is, lambda provide equivalent functionality but is still different from function in many/all other ways.

@rand'Chris Thanks. I clarified the want up-front. the template with index_sequence calls the template function once for each template index k=0,...,n-1. Having k of template kind is needed e.g. when utilizing static arrays of dimension k.

@rand'Chris int n as seen inside template<int n> is called a non-type template parameter.

"when I collapse a class'es code" -- By this you mean a function of your specific editor that hides the contents of matching braces? Is it a one-step process in your editor? The editors I'm familiar with would require clicking each member function individually to collapse it, which seems like a lot of work for little benefit.

@heapunderrun Thanks for the link. I've never seen (noticed) code using templates to declare an array size.

@rand'Chris I'd say this is raher common. For example, the std::array is itself a class template, with the first parameter indicating element type, and the second parameter indicating the number of elements.

@heapunderrun Yup, it just looked really strange without a generic type.

I think templated lambda is the simplest option here. It can be used like as shown below:
template<int n>
struct A{
  double x;
  
  
  void eval(){
    [this]<std::size_t... k>(std::index_sequence<k...>)
    { 
        (decltype([]<int i>(){x+=exp(k);){}.template operator()<k>(), ...); 
    }(std::make_index_sequence<n>{});
  }
};

Working demo
